# Kubuntu 14.10 Wireless DNS Issue

Tags: networking, wifi, kubuntu

I'm quite new to using Kubuntu and have run into issues with the wireless connection on Kubuntu 14.10. The wireless connection says that it is connected, and I can ping IP addresses of other devices on my local network and websites on the internet (such as `119.224.142.57` which is google.com). But if I try to perform a system update or browse to websites it is unable to resolve them, leading me to believe this is a DNS issue.

Previously I have been able to run

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

and this fixed the issue, but not it just says `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.
I have also tried

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

and selected `<yes>`, but this has also proved to be fruitless.

What should I be doing to get the wireless connection working properly again?

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing seems to be an issue that the developers overlooked. Use an Ethernet cable, as it is an temporary workaround until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Something isn't going right, I tried adding a wired connection under _Connection Editor_ using default settings (IP is assigned using the routers DHCP), but the ethernet has a state of unavailable when I call `nm-tool`.